# dotnet test doesn't recursively search folders for .csproj with wildcards

Tags: .net, testing, automated-tests, xunit, csproj

I want to run all tests in several dotnet core C# test projects.

From the root folder if I run 'dotnet test **/*.test.csproj' it will only run the tests one folder down.
From the root folder if I run 'dotnet test **/**/*.test.csproj' it will only run the tests two folders down.

How can I get 'dotnet test' to recursively check all folders for a *.test.csproj project? i.e. run test from both projects above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `dotnet test` without any argument in the root folder. Make sure you added a [.sln file](https://github.com/guillaumesasdy/pm-api-asp-dotnet-core/blob/dev/ProjectManagement.sln) that defines the path for all the projects of your solution, including the test projects. It works for my [GitHub repository for an API](https://github.com/guillaumesasdy/pm-api-asp-dotnet-core) with test files in folders:

- `Api.IntegrationTests\`
- `Logic.Tests\`
- `Subfolder\Another.Tests\`

I added the third test project just on my local computer (you will not see it on the GitHub repository) to make sure it works:

> Test run for ...\Subfolder\Another.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Another.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)
>
> Test run for ...\Logic.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Logic.Tests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)
>
> Test run for ...\Api.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Api.IntegrationTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)